# mysql_real_escape_string() say Access denied for user 'drrifae'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I userd mysql_real_escape_string(), that was ok on my localhost (on my computer run by xampp) but when I upload it to **Linux** server function (mysql_real_escape_string()) say **Access denied for user 'drrifae'@'localhost'**

This is my code:

```
  if($_POST['message']!=""){
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $message=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
       $ip=$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

include('../include/connection.php');
$sql="INSERT INTO `contact_feedback` (`type`, `ip`, `message`, `name`, `email`) VALUES ('$type', '$ip', '$message', '$name', '$email'); ";
        $result=mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_query());
        if($result){
            echo $_SESSION['message']='true';
                $mailMessage=wordwrap($message,70);
                $mailMessage.='\n \n'.$email.'\n'.$name.'\n \n'.$ip;
            if($type=='1'){
                $subject="contact";
            }else if($type=='0'){
                $subject="feedback";
             }
            mail('info@rifae.com',$subject,$mailMessage,$email);
        }else{
            $_SESSION['message']='false';
        }
    }
```

BUT I CAN't USE mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: @kingkero please explain more about mysqli and pdo and post it as Answerm Thanks

Comment: @kingkero what kind of connection is my mysql connection? PDO or MYSQLi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$message=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
//...
include('../include/connection.php');
```

You currently use `mysql_real_escape_string()` **before** you `include` the connection - this is why you have no access.

---

Also keep in mind that `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and hence should not be used in new code. You can use PDO or MySQLi instead. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/1557526) for more information. (If you follow the links in the post, you'll also find tutorials on how to use either).

---

`mysql_` is neither MySQLi nor PDO, you should be able to see which is available via `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Thank you, mr.kermani told me this too http://stackoverflow.com/users/3176270/kermani